# Only one 'enable_page_level_ads' allowed per page

Tags: asp.net, adsense

I am currently working on a website with existing Auto Ads with the following code block:

```
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
        google_ad_client: "ca-pub-XXXXX",
        enable_page_level_ads: true
    });
</script>
```

and few ads with the same code as below:

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
    var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>
<script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/XXXXX/Desktop_Header', [
        [970, 250],
        [970, 90],
        [728, 90]
        ], 'div-gpt-ad-XXXXXX-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
    });
</script>
```

Given that, I am having the following issue in the dev tool console.

> adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one 'enable_page_level_ads' allowed per
>   page.

That error disappears when the former script block was deleted but as far as I understand [Auto Ads can co-exist with other ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7478040). Up until now, I cannot find a specific solution even from the Google forum itself.

Answer (score 4):

...because you appear to have multiple page-level ad codes in your site.

You only need one.

I just faced the same error few days back, my problem is that I had multiple adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push in a code because on master, child and sometimes partial page.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: adsbygoogle.push() search this in your code, if it appear more then once, then you need to remove extra ones.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently having the same problem, and when I into my code, I had added one set of google ads code in the header while coding the page and another I had added using the plugin. I removed it from my plugin. It worked for me.